# Chatbot em Python com NLTK

Tags: python-3.x, regex, nltk

Eu sou iniciante em python, a algum tempo tenho me interessado em Mineração de Textos e gostaria de pedir uma ajuda com uma duvida em um projeto.

A algum tempo venho estudando como utilizar a Biblioteca NLTK do Python para elaborar um chatbot.

Eu até cheguei a elaborar alguns códigos, mas ficou uma duvida.

O meu código:

```
#coding: utf-8 

from nltk.chat.util import Chat, reflections 

pairs = [ 
    [ 
        r'oi', 
        ['olá', 'Como vai?', 'Tudo Bem?',] 
    ], 
] 

def bob_bot(): 
    print("Como posso te ajudar hoje?") 
    chat = Chat(pairs, reflections) 
    chat.converse() 

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    bob_bot()
```

Eu percebi que nessa tupla 'pairs' o modulo nltk.chat.util usa uma função do modulo 're' do python pra criar os dialogos do bot.

No modulo nltk.chat.util ele pega o conteudo da tupla e usa essa função:

`[(re.compile(x, re.IGNORECASE),y) for (x,y) in pairs]`

pra transformar o conteudo de 'pairs' em:

```
[(re.compile('oi', re.IGNORECASE), ['olá', 'Como vai?', 'Tudo Bem?'])]
```

A minha duvida é saber se tem como pegar os dialogos de um arquivo de texto, colocar eles dentro da tupla 'pairs' como se fossem uma sentença, ex: 'Como vai?', 'Tudo Bem?'. Pra que quando eu rodar o codigo o python leia os diálogos de dentro do arquivo de texto.

Alguém que tenha experiencia, pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 3):

Você pode criar um arquivo CSV, use o ponto e virgula como delimitador para separar os campos, o primeiro campo será a expressão regular, e o segundo campo a resposta. Note que removi as aspas simples e as virgulas, e adicionei **barra vertical**, ela se como delimitador para separar cada resposta.

Arquivo **chat.csv**

```
oi;olá|Como vai?|Tudo Bem?
```

Agora é só abrir o arqui pelo Python:

```python
with open('chat.csv', newline='') as File:  
  reader = csv.reader(File, delimiter=';')
  for linha in reader:
    add = [
      r"{}".format(linha[0]), # Expressão regular
      [] # Resposta
    ]
    # Adiciona cada resposta na tupla "add[1]"
    for x in linha[1].split('|'): add[1].append(x)
    # Adiciona "add" em "pairs"
    pairs.append(add)
```

Agora, logo abaixo se der um `print` terá a saída:

```
[
  [ 'oi', [ 'olá', 'Como vai?', 'Tudo Bem?' ] ]
]
```

Se você modificar o arquivo **chat.csv**

```
oi;olá|Como vai?|Tudo Bem?
qual seu nome?;Bob
```

Terá a saída:

```
[
  [ 'oi', [ 'olá', 'Como vai?', 'Tudo Bem?' ] ],
  [ 'qual seu nome?', [ 'Bob' ] ]
]
```

E quando executar o boot:

```
Como posso te ajudar hoje?
> qual seu nome
Bob
```

Veja [funcionando em repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/RedundantGregariousComments)

Answer (score 1):

(supondo que vale linux/mac/unix)

Sugestão criar um ficheiro "chat.py", um ficheiro "input.txt" e:

```
$ cat chat.py
... o ficheiro da pergunta

$ cat in.txt
oi
oi
oi
adeus

$ python chat.py < in.txt > out.txt

$ paste -d'\n' out.txt in.txt
Como posso te ajudar hoje?
oi
>Tudo Bem?
oi
>Como vai?
oi
>olá
até depois
>None
adeus
>None

>quit

None
```